# relative import when using imp, __init__.py behaves differently

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, relative-import

I am using python 3.7. When using `imp`, I noticed relative imports work differently depending on where the relative import happens.

For example, I have the following directory:

```
.
├── __init__.py
└── dir2
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── a.py
    └── b.py
```

and file content as follows:

```sh
~/personal/dir1 via  v3.7.7 via C py372
❯ cat dir2/__init__.py
from .a import default
print("default is", default)

~/personal/dir1 via  v3.7.7 via C py372
❯ cat dir2/a.py

default = 12

~/personal/dir1 via  v3.7.7 via C py372
❯ cat dir2/b.py
from .a import default
print("default is", default)

~/personal/dir1 via  v3.7.7 via C py372
```

And I use `imp.load_source` for both `dir2/__init__.py` and `dir2/b.py`, I got the following results:

```py
❯ ipython
Python 3.7.7 (default, May  6 2020, 04:59:01)
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.16.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: import imp
/Users/user/anaconda3/envs/py372/bin/ipython:1: DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
  #!/Users/user/anaconda3/envs/py372/bin/python

In [2]: imp.load_source("m", "dir2/__init__.py")
default is 12
Out[2]: <module 'm' from 'dir2/__init__.py'>

In [3]: imp.load_source("m", "dir2/b.py")
---------------------------------------------------------
ImportError             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-40c4f63c0bb1> in <module>
----> 1 imp.load_source("m", "dir2/b.py")

~/anaconda3/envs/py372/lib/python3.7/imp.py in load_source(name, pathname, file)
    167     spec = util.spec_from_file_location(name, pathname, loader=loader)
    168     if name in sys.modules:
--> 169         module = _exec(spec, sys.modules[name])
    170     else:
    171         module = _load(spec)

~/anaconda3/envs/py372/lib/python3.7/importlib/_bootstrap.py in _exec(spec, module)

~/anaconda3/envs/py372/lib/python3.7/importlib/_bootstrap_external.py in exec_module(self, module)

~/anaconda3/envs/py372/lib/python3.7/importlib/_bootstrap.py in _call_with_frames_removed(f, *args, **kwds)

~/personal/dir1/dir2/b.py in <module>
----> 1 from .a import default
      2 print("default is", default)

ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Why `imp.load_source` behaves differently for `__init__.py` versus other python file?

Comment: "I noticed relative imports work differently depending on where the relative import happens" - that's the entire point of a relative import.

Answer (score 1):

Relative imports are not a directory traversal mechanism. They are for importing other contents of the package in which they appear.

When you call `imp.load_source("m", "dir2/__init__.py")`, Python thinks you're trying to load a package named `m` whose `__init__.py` is `dir2/__init__.py`. In this context, relative imports are relative to the package `m`, and they search for submodules in directory `dir2`.

When you call `imp.load_source("m", "dir2/b.py")`, Python thinks you're trying to load a top-level module named `m`. There is no package for relative imports to be relative to, and relative imports are meaningless in this context.

Comment: thanks. this behavior is specific for python 3, right? in other words, both should work in python 2?

Comment: @qkhhly: I would not expect this behavior to be different in Python 2.

Comment: does that mean i should never use relative imports in files other than `__init__.py`? this does not sound right to me.

Comment: @qkhhly: On the contrary, the problems are due to the way you're using `load_source`. Using `load_source` at all is likely a bad approach - you should probably change how you're organizing your code.

Comment: i'd prefer not to use `imp.load_source`, but i'm using `apache-airflow` and that's how it imports custom-defined `DAGS`. i have no way to change that. it would be great if you could elaborate a bit more on how relative import should be used in python 3 in cases with and without using `imp.load_source`.

Comment: @qkhhly: The relative imports are fine. The problem isn't with relative imports. The problem is that you're trying to import a package submodule as a top-level package. I do not know enough about Apache Airflow or about the situation that motivated this question to be able to tell you how to change your usage of Apache Airflow.